# Dice Rolls for PBEMs

Tags: dice, online-roleplaying, online-resources, play-by-post

Is there an online dice roller that has some kind of confirmation mechanism so it can be used by forum/PBEM games?

For example?

> Bob: "I kick open the door"
>   MC: Roll here [gives link]
>   Bob: [clicks link to roll]
>   MC: [Checks result]

I'm not looking for roll20 or similar, this needs to be a one-shot roll resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used http://www.pbegames.com/roller/ for this in the past.
You can enter a list of email addresses, and the dice roll gets emailed to all the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use orokos.com for PBEM or PBP.

Otherwise, you can do a couple things. If your heart isn't set on email or a specific forum as the mechanism, you can play over your own subforum using a site like rpg.net or even Slack which have built in dice rollers.

Alternately, for real time (both you and the player are online at the same time), you can use Roll20. For PBEM, this is not likely to be the norm, but it is an option.

I should note that all will require an account, so as a one time only thing it might be sub-optimal. In that case, you can use [Stack's dice roller](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16836/dice-roller-formatting-tests-playground), assuming the other person has a Stack Exchange account already as well.